# Digitizing toolbar is gone in QGIS

Tags: qgis, digitizing, toolbar

For some reason the digitizing toolbar is gone in QGIS even though I checked the box:
[image]

Do you have experience with this and know how to get the toolbar back?

EDIT:
When making it as small as possible it still doesnt pop up and it is also not in the dropdown in the red circle:[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove (untick) it, close QGIS, then add it back?

Comment: Have you checked if you undocked the toolbar and hid it behind you main window?

Comment: @JGH Tried it and didnt work unfortunatey

Comment: @Erik Can you elaborate? I checked if it is under the layers and browser part on the left but it wasnt there, I dont know how to check behind the main window.

Comment: Just make it as small as possible.

Comment: @Erik tried making it as small as possible but still cant see it (look at the edit in the post)

Comment: De-activate all toolbars one after the other (starting with those of the plugins) to see if it comes back. When you're just left with only the digitizing toolbar activated, restart QGIS. Maybe also try a new user profile.

Answer (score 4):

I have had issues with disappearing panels (dataPlotly specifically).  When that happens I have to go into the Interface Customization settings and reset it.  Try playing around in there to see if it brings the toolbar back.  I'm using 3.18.

[image]